# Use shell provided by non-root user

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell, rsync

What is a good way for a non-root user to use an executable that is not in the system's list of shells as if it were the user's actual shell?

I'm trying to do this with two different versions of bash. The older version is the actual shell. It shows up in `chsh -l`, is located at the usual `/bin/bash`, and is what the system considers my shell. I want a newer version to masquerade as my shell. I have it compiled in a directory. Right now I have this in my `.bashrc`.

```
if [ $(echo $0) != $PATH_TO_NEW_SHELL_EXECUTABLE ]; then
    export SHELL=$PATH_TO_NEW_SHELL_EXECUTABLE
    exec "$SHELL" "$@"
fi
```

The problem I have with this is that commands run through ssh on this machine hang on the `exec` line. `rsync` and `scp` also hang. For example, the following will hang.

```
ssh user@host false
```

I don't understand this behavior. Otherwise, this works. I can even start an interactive ssh session just fine.

How can I solve this specific problem and more generally what is the best way to go about simulating a properly installed shell?

Answer (score 0):

When I try to replace the login shell (by an other/new shell) with exec, I lost the tty:

```
10869  1118 root        0.0  0.0  \_ sshd: username [priv] 
10907 10869 username    0.0  0.0  |   \_ sshd: username@notty  
10908 10907 username    0.0  0.0  |       \_ /bin/bash
```

this might be the problem.

Comment: Are you sure it will be a child? It sounds unlikely that the `exec` shell command behaves so differently from the `exec()` function.

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right. The `exec` command **replaces** the shell without a knew process // I made a litle test which shows me, that we lost the tty // updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't hang. Your command wasn't run, but your new shell is here, interactive and without a prompt

```
test@myhost:~$ ssh localhost false
test@localhost's password: 
echo $0
/home/test/bin/myshell
echo $#
0
```

Now if in .bashrc before the exec you add these lines:

```
echo $# "$0" "$@"
sleep 300
```

You can see what happens:

```
test@myhost:~$ ssh localhost false uselessparm1 uselessparm2
0 bash
```

Beside:

```
|-sshd(25350)---sshd(18920)---sshd(18925)---bash(18926)---sleep(18927)

$ cat /proc/18926/cmdline |tr '\0' '\n'
bash
-c
false uselessparm1 uselessparm2
```

sshd will actually run `bash -c 'false uselessparm1 uselessparm2'`

But for some reason, in this context the command line arguments exist but $1 $2 ... are not set in the shell ($#=0). So the exec will never run anything else than the new shell

You should put your trick in ~/.bash_profile (executed at login) and leave ~/.bashrc alone.